# best debug procedure for caret variable selection 'functions'?

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

I'm trying to use caret's 'filter' functions to do variable selections before training a model using the following code:

```
filterCtrl <- sbfControl(functions = rfSBF, 
                         method = "repeatedcv", 
                         repeats = 5, 
                         verbose = TRUE)
set.seed(10)
rfWithFilter <- sbf(x, y, sbfControl = filterCtrl)
```

I believe this is pretty much this is an example from the caret website on sbf ('selection by filter').  As you can see I'm using the predefined 'rfSBF' functions. http://topepo.github.io/caret/filters.html However when I run over my dataset I get the error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "NA not permitted in predictors"
>   In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

And for warnings:

> In model.response(mf, "numeric") : NAs introduced by coercion

Now it appears that something in my data is being coerced into a numeric which the fitting algorithm hates because it's random forest and there are NAs in the predictors.  So I *think* I have an understanding of the problem, but since I don't know exactly where the problem occurs (because caret variable selection uses passed functions and my problem is occurring in one of these 7 functions) I'm not sure where this occurs, so I can't work backwards from the line in the code to what I need to do to my data set to fix the problem.  I figure I could just run through the functions one at a time (fit, pred, etc. etc.)  But I'm not sure exactly in which order or how it's run (or even where the source code is to try and deduce this procedure). Any ideas?

As a reminder these are the predefined functions that are passed to filterCtrl for rfSBF:

```
> rfSBF
$summary
function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
    if (is.character(data$obs)) 
        data$obs <- factor(data$obs, levels = lev)
    postResample(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
}
<environment: namespace:caret>

$fit
function (x, y, ...) 
{
    if (ncol(x) > 0) {
        loadNamespace("randomForest")
        randomForest::randomForest(x, y, ...)
    }
    else nullModel(y = y)
}
<environment: namespace:caret>

$pred
function (object, x) 
{
    if (class(object) == "nullModel") {
        tmp <- predict(object, x)
        if (!is.null(object$levels)) {
            out <- cbind(data.frame(pred = tmp), as.data.frame(predict(object, 
                x, type = "prob")))
        }
        else out <- tmp
    }
    else {
        tmp <- predict(object, x)
        if (is.factor(object$y)) {
            out <- cbind(data.frame(pred = tmp), as.data.frame(predict(object, 
                x, type = "prob")))
        }
        else out <- tmp
    }
    out
}
<environment: namespace:caret>

$score
function (x, y) 
{
    if (is.factor(y)) 
        anovaScores(x, y)
    else gamScores(x, y)
}
<environment: namespace:caret>

$filter
function (score, x, y) 
score <= 0.05
<environment: namespace:caret>
```

Comment: you could start with debugonce(sbf.default) and walk through the function.

Comment: I didn't even know that function existed. Thanks!